# Can I still uses the method of logarithmic differentiation to simplify complicated functions if the the range of that function includes 0?

Tags: calculus

The method of log differentiation refers to taking the natural log of both sides of an equation to simply an complication functions evolving lots of multiplication and divisions and exponents.

But say y= something, and we talk natural log, to get lny=ln(something). **Do we have to make sure the range (y) will never be/include 0?**

Comment: You can do that *locally*. Restrict $y$ to some domain $G$. If $y$ never vanishes on $G$, then you can do that.